# How to set Ubuntu 18.04 to leave 5% charge in notebook battery?

Tags: power-management, battery

We recently bought a Lenovo notebook, which has two batteries (inside + one quickly changeable outside).

I can see that Ubuntu 18.04 is using only one battery at a time, consumes it fully, then it automatically starts using the second one, that is OK.

But the issue is that when it drains the first battery, it really drains it, to 0%, 0.2 Wh.

**The question**: How can I set Ubuntu 18.04 to leave ex.: 5% charge in the batteries and not drain it fully to 0%?

In this current default way, **Ubuntu is killing the expensive batteries** without brain. Full discharge is bad for batteries.

Also to note, strange, when I set the "full indicator" at the "notification area" to show me the remaining percentage and time, it shows the remaining time for only the currently used battery, but the percentage is for both the battery. Any idea how to fix the remaining time part to show it for the two battery?

I can see that Windows 10 is only using up to 5% of the battery, then it goes to the second one, so it should be doable using the OS.